# Issue with header location and http response code

Tags: php

```
    $models = new Models();
    $myModel = $models->getURL($modUrl, 1);
    if (!$myModel) {
        header('Location: /our-models', true, 404);
    }
```

If I use `header('Location: /our-models', true, 404);` nothing happens (the execution of the page continue), but `header('Location: /our-models');` do the redirect.

Something is wrong with my redirect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP standard documents the response code of 301/302 for redirects such like this one.

Browsers will not redirect when a 404 response code is sent.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx